# Is it possible to add properties to collections in powershell?

Tags: collections, powershell, properties

I've got a very large array of objects obtained by a normal Get-ChildItem, and I need to be able to index them by a variety of different properties. I've got a set of hashtables that I've made that index them by those properties, but right now it's just a bunch of collections that must be built and managed separately. At one point it occurred to me that it would be nice to just add the hashtables onto the base collection as properties such as "ByPath" "ByGuid" etc. The code to build it would just draw together the individual statements I already have:

```
$items = Get-ChildItem -recurse blahblah
$items | Add-Member -membertype NoteProperty -name "ByGuid" -value (Get-ItemsByGuid)
$items | Add-Member -memberType NoteProperty -name "ByPath" -value (Get-ItemsByPath)
$items
```

Unfortunately, while this doesn't throw on execution, it doesn't do anything. The properties exist and are visible with Get-Member, but they're always null when interrogated and throw when being set afterwards.

`Property 'ByGuid' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At line:1 char:14`
`+ $items. <<<< ByGuid = $itemsByGuid`
`+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException`
`+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException`

lies!

Is there any reason that this shouldn't be possible based on what I'm trying to do? Or is there some reason for the oddly mixed messages I'm getting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is possible and you are on the right track. Just remember that the pipeline enumerates collections (including arrays). You need to account for that enumeration otherwise you wind up adding the properties to each item in the array rather than to the array itself.  You can workaround this enumeration by using the comma operator like so:

```
$items = ,$items | Add-Member NoteProperty ByGuid (Get-ItemsByGuid) -PassThru
$items = ,$items | Add-Member NoteProperty ByPath (Get-ItemsByPath) -PassThru
```

Note that if you want to check the members on the $items array using `Get-Member`, you need to use the same trick:

```
,$items | Get-Member
```

The `,` operator simply wraps the target in another array where the target is the only element.  When the pipeline enumerates this new array, we get the original array as the only output into the pipeline.

Comment: Keith, you're my hero. I feel like I owe you a six-pack by now or something. I've been shaky on the whole wrapping/unwrapping thing since I started, specifically on cases like this. I had envisioned Add-Member as being more of a reference-type operation than a value-type one, and it seems that the comma operator in combination with -PassThru and an assignment are all necessary...very little chance I would have gotten that on my own. Thanks a ton!

Comment: No problem.  This is one of those areas where PowerShell does the right thing most of the time i.e. automatic enumeration is nice.  However, as you've found, there are times when you don't want it. Even though it isn't obvious how to avoid the enumeration, at least it is easy to accomplish. :-)

Comment: You could also use "Add-Member -InputObject $items ..."